# Without Zoom Raycaster not Working on Threejs

Tags: reactjs, raycasting, threejs-editor

I am using threejs boxgeometry. In boxgeometry I used label(It is also a 3D cube which looks as label). I'm using raycaster as the onclick function for the 3D cube(label).
When I click on that cube(label) It should display the cube's(labels) details.
It is displaying the details when we create big label or when we are using zoom.
But if I create small label without zoom and click on the cube(label) it is not displaying the details.

I am using this :

```
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, threedwidth / threedheight, 0.1, 1000);
const pointer = new THREE.Vector2();
const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

window.addEventListener('pointerdown', (event) => {

  let templabelarray = []

  if (this.labels.length > 0) {
    pointer.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    pointer.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

    raycaster.setFromCamera(pointer, camera);
    var index = 99;
    const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(this.scene.children);
    
    if (intersects.length > 1) {
      index = Math.floor(intersects[0].faceIndex / 2);
    if (index == 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.labels.length; i++) {
          if (this.labels[i].typename == 'Left') {
            templabelarray.push(this.labels[i]);
          }
        }
      }  
      if (index == 1) {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.labels.length; i++) {
          if (this.labels[i].typename == 'right') {
            templabelarray.push(this.labels[i]);
          }
        }
      }  
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to I accomplimsh or any guidance, reference appreciated.

Comment: Your code is hardly a reproducible example. There is no `this` and `templabelarray` is always empty...

Comment: Now you can go to my code. I added full code. Here I added 2 index, But I have 5 index like 'Front', 'Top', 'Back', 'Right' & 'Left'.

Comment: How would we run this code to reproduce your error?

Comment: I got the solution,Now it is working fine.. Previously I used "window.innerWidth" & "window.innerWidth", but I used one separate canvas, so now I used canvaswidth and canvasheight instead of "window.innerWidth" & "window.innerWidth".
Thank you so much for your information and support.

Answer (score 0):

Try using canvas instead of window because window will not support while using canvas

```
      const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
      const offsetX = event.clientX - rect.left;
      const offsetY = event.clientY - rect.top;
      pointer.x = (offsetX / canvas.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
      pointer.y = -(offsetY / canvas.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
```